# How to make Facebook App Events works on ios15?

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, ios15, facebook-analytics

On iOS15 don't see app events in Events Manager. Both on "overview" and "test events" tabs.

Answer (score 7):

There is one important thing missed in facebook app events docs. To make facebook app events work on iOS 14+ app MUST request user for tracking.
Here is example:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {[weak self] in
            self?.requestTracking()
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func requestTracking(){
                if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { (status) in
                        switch status{
                        case .authorized:
                            Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
                            Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
                            Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
                            break

                        case .denied:
                            Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
                            Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false
                            Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false

                            break
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                    })
                }
        }
```

Otherwise Facebook app events will work only if app been authorised throw Facebook sign in.

Comment: as mentioned in FB docs:
"Get Device Consent
Starting with iOS 14.5, you will need to set isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled and log each time you give a device permission to share data with Facebook. If a device provides consent, set Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true. If a device does not allow tracking, set Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false."